# Generating a JS-client based on a ASP.NET WebAPI Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, proxy-classes

In modern web-projects that use RESTful API's we often see AJAX-calls like the one below littered around our JavaScript-files.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myapp.baseUrl + 'Api/Note',
    data: ko.mapping.toJSON(note),
    contentType: 'application/json',
}).done(function (response) {
    // do something
}).fail(function (jqxhr) {
    // do something else
});
```

I love WebAPI, I love Knockout and I love tying the two together. However these AJAX-calls are quite verbose and contain all kinds of details that I am not really interested in. So instead, I create a wrapper around these methods:

```
myapp.api.saveNote(note)
```

However this still requires me to actually write a wrapper containing the AJAX-call. I was wondering if you could actually **generate these wrappers**. In essence, I would be generating a JS-based client for my WebAPI, similar to how Java and .NET can generate clients based on WSDL's.

1. Has this been done before?
2. Are there other ways to tie ASP.NET WebAPI and JavaScript together without writing a bunch of AJAX boilerplate code?
3. In other words, are there frameworks for creating JS-interfaces based on server-side interfaces like ASP.NET WebAPI?

I've already looked at amplifyJS but this only partially solves the problem. I am looking for a solution that actually creates an interface based on the WebAPI-controllers in my solution. If this does not exist, I will start tinkering myself. I've already got an idea for a `WebAPIClientGenerator` that uses reflection to iterate over all `ApiController`'s.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

<s>Just found a project called: **ProxyApi**</s>

> ProxyApi is a library that automatically creates JavaScript proxy
>   objects for your ASP.NET MVC and WebApi Controllers.

GitHub: https://github.com/stevegreatrex/ProxyApi

Blog: http://blog.greatrexpectations.com/2012/11/06/proxyapi-automatic-javascript-proxies-for-webapi-and-mvc/

ProxyApi generated invalid JavaScript for my solution which contained over a hundred separate WebAPI actions. This is probably because ProxyApi does not cover all WebApi features such as custom ActionName attributes. Moreover the ProxyApi library is a bit on the bulky side to my taste. There has to be a more efficient way to do this...

So I decided to take a look at the ASP.NET WebAPI source code and it turns out WebAPI has self-describing functionality built into it. You can use the following code from anywhere in your ASP.NET solution to access WebAPI metadata:

```
var apiExplorer = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer();
```

Based on the output from `apiExplorer.ApiDescriptions`, I rolled my own metadata provider:

```
public class MetadataController : Controller
{
    public virtual PartialViewResult WebApiDescription()
    {
        var apiExplorer = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer();
        var apiMethods = apiExplorer.ApiDescriptions.Select(ad => new ApiMethodModel(ad)).ToList();
        return PartialView(apiMethods);
    }

    public class ApiMethodModel
    {
        public string Method { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string ControllerName { get; set; }
        public string ActionName { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ApiParameterModel> Parameters { get; set; }

        public ApiMethodModel(ApiDescription apiDescription)
        {
            Method = apiDescription.HttpMethod.Method;
            Url = apiDescription.RelativePath;
            ControllerName = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
            ActionName = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
            Parameters = apiDescription.ParameterDescriptions.Select(pd => new ApiParameterModel(pd));
        }
    }

    public class ApiParameterModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsUriParameter { get; set; }

        public ApiParameterModel(ApiParameterDescription apiParameterDescription)
        {
            Name = apiParameterDescription.Name;
            IsUriParameter = apiParameterDescription.Source == ApiParameterSource.FromUri;
        }
    }
}
```

Use this controller in conjunction with the following view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Awesome.Controllers.MetadataController.ApiMethodModel>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var awesome = awesome || {};

    awesome.api = {
        metadata: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
    };

    $.each(awesome.api.metadata, function (i, action) {
        if (!awesome.api[action.ControllerName]) {
            awesome.api[action.ControllerName] = {};
        }
        awesome.api[action.ControllerName][action.ActionName] = function (parameters) {
            var url = '/' + action.Url;
            var data;
            $.each(action.Parameters, function (j, parameter) {
                if (parameters[parameter.Name] === undefined) {
                    console.log('Missing parameter: ' + parameter.Name + ' for API: ' + action.ControllerName + '/' + action.ActionName);
                } else if (parameter.IsUriParameter) {
                    url = url.replace("{" + parameter.Name + "}", parameters[parameter.Name]);
                } else if (data === undefined) {
                    data = parameters[parameter.Name];
                } else {
                    console.log('Detected multiple body-parameters for API: ' + action.ControllerName + '/' + action.ActionName);
                }
            });
            return $.ajax({
                type: action.Method,
                url: url,
                data: data,
                contentType: 'application/json'
            });
        };
    });
</script>
```

The controller will use the `ApiExplorer` to generate metadata about all available WebAPI actions. The view will render this data as JSON and then execute some JavaScript to transform this data to actual executable JavaScript functions.

To use this little bit of magic, insert the following line in the head of your Layout page **after** your jQuery reference.

```
@Html.Action(MVC.Metadata.WebApiDescription())
```

From now on, you can make your WebAPI calls look like this:

```
// GET: /Api/Notes?id={id}
awesome.api.Notes.Get({ id: id }).done(function () {
    // .. do something cool       
});

// POST: /Api/Notes
awesome.api.Notes.Post({ form: formData }).done(function () {
    // .. do something cool       
});
```

This simple proxy will automatically distinguish query string parameters from request body parameters. Missing parameters or multiple body-parameters will generate an error to prevent typo's or other common WebAPI development errors.

Comment: How would I retrieve List using Get method? Looks like Get always expects ID parameter

Comment: I figured it out, I just added
`if (typeof parameters != 'undefined' && parameters != null) {`
statement around parameter checking block and added
`url = url.replace(""{"" + parameter.Name + ""}"", '');`
in the else part

Comment: This is one of the best answer's I've ever seen on SO. Thanks so much.

Comment: Where is `MVC` defined in MVC 4?

Comment: `MVC.Metadata.WebApiDescription()` is generated by T4MVC. If you do not use T4MVC in your project you need to specify a string that points to your action. E.g. `@Url.Action("~/Metadata/WebApiDescription")`

Comment: for POST and PUT requests, data has to be converted to string using JSON.stringify

Answer (score 4):

I'm working on the Swagger open-source toolchain **NSwag** for .NET: With this tool you can **generate the TypeScript client for a single or multiple Web API controllers**.

In the UI just

1. Select the Web API DLL
2. Select the controller classes
3. Generate TypeScript client code (in your case, select the `JQueryCallbacks` or `JQueryPromises` template)

Have a look at http://nswag.org

FYI: [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) is a language which gets transpiled to JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

This excellent another project allows you to do what you asked for.
This poject auto-generates JavaScript proxies for MVC and WebApi controllers.
And, this project covers WebApi features such as custom ActionName attributes.
With this project, you will have also the Intellisense.

http://jsnet.codeplex.com/

[Example of Intellisense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXMo0.png)

```js
window.test = function test() {
/// <summary>
///This example works.
///You have the Intellisense. It's great!!!
///No hard coded url.
///</summary>

//-- settings of ajax request.
var a = $dpUrlSet.Customer.Create.$action0.$AjaxSettings();

//-- your parameters of action method
a.data.name = "Scott Gu";
a.data.address = "Somewhere in Redmond";

//-- stringify
a.data = JSON.stringify(a.data);

//-- send ajax request
var xhr = $.ajax(a);

xhr.success(function (id) {
    /// <summary>Response of ajax request</summary>

    //-- settings of ajax request.
    var a = $dpUrlSet.Customer.Update.$action0.$AjaxSettings();

    //-- your parameters of action method
    a.data.id = id;
    a.data.name = "Scott Gu";
    a.data.address = "Somewhere in Seattle";

    //-- stringify
    a.data = JSON.stringify(a.data);

    //-- send ajax request
    var xhr = $.ajax(a);

});
}
```